# How do I set a horizontal alignment with Navigation Drawer concept for an Android app in Android Studio like in this picture?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, horizontal-scrolling, slidingmenu

This [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zujn1.png) contains an image which has an Android app with sliding menu. Within that menu, under **Filter By** section, we can find a list of items arranged horizontally, namely **Delivery**, **Dine In**, **Night Life**. How do we do that in Android Studio? An answer which suggests a scrollable effect for that horizontal alignment will also be helpful.

Comment: the original Sliding Menu is deprecated.

Comment: @Polarbear0106 I didn't get you. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: There used to be a way to make sliding menus but it became deprecated(recomended to not use it) for some reason. It causes crashes because it hasn't been updated in ages. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: Oh, thank you. I guess it is navigation drawer now. Is there a way to get the above effect using Navigation Drawer @Polarbear0106? I will also edit the question.